# Not delete list of objects by clause "in"

Tags: android, realm

Android Studio 3.2, Realm 5.8.0

In Realm I has 3 merchants with `id=1,2,3`.

Now I delete all merchants with `ids= 1,2`

So I use "`in`" clause for this.

Here snippet:

```
   public static void updateList(final List<Merchant> thatMerchantsList) {
     Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            try {
                realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                      Long[] idsToDeleteArray = new 
                      Long[itemNotExistInThatMerchants.size()];
                      for (int index = 0; index <                          
                         itemNotExistInThatMerchants.size(); index++) {
                          Merchant merchant = 
                          itemNotExistInThatMerchants.get(index);
                          idsToDeleteArray[index] = merchant.getId();
                       }

                      RealmResults<Merchant> localMerchantsForDelete = 
                           realm.where(Merchant.class).in(Merchant.ID, 
                              idsToDeleteArray).findAll();
                      boolean isDelete = 
                         localMerchantsForDelete.deleteAllFromRealm();
                      Debug.d(TAG, "updateMerchantList: idsToDeleteArray =  " + Arrays.toString(idsToDeleteArray)
                          + " -> localMerchantsForDelete_size = " + localMerchantsForDelete.size() + " -> isDelete = " + isDelete);
                     }
                });
            } finally {
                realm.close();
                Debug.d(TAG, "updateMerchantList: finish");
            }
}
```

In logcat you can see:

```
idsToDeleteArray =  [1, 2] -> localMerchantsForDelete_size = 0 -> isDelete = true
```

As you can see the `localMerchantsForDelete_size  = 0`. Why?

As result the 2 merchants not delete from Realm.

Comment: `localMerchantsForDelete_size  = 0` because you're checking its size AFTER you've deleted the items. O_O